# Personal MathJax Macros/Shortcuts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax

I think it would be beneficial if in our profile, we had the option to define some MathJax shortcuts, much like how we define LaTeX shortcuts in the headers of our LaTeX-Documents. This would save users time in writing answers.

For example, I would like to save shortcuts similar to these for my account, so I don't have to waste time typing:

```
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
```

I think this would be reasonably easy to implement, and it should be welcomed esp. by our more dedicated users.

Comment: Alternatively, if there were a foreseen problem with saving JaX shortcuts to an account, as accounts occasionally get deleted while the posts stay behind, being able to paste your own \newcommand set in header would be nifty.

Comment: @J.W.Perry That problem would be resolved if the MathJax script simply converts your macro to 'normal MathJax' upon posting. I think there are many ways to easily resolve that issue.

Comment: Ahh quite so! That would be nifty squared.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11870/specific-latex-commands-for-users-account, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8834/remember-own-latex-commands and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/can-we-simplify-the-mathbb-command

Comment: If this isn't possible, I'd like to note that it's more convenient sometimes to simply write \Bbb Z, say, for $\Bbb Z$. Shorter and no need for brackets.

Comment: I like this suggestion, since it neatly addresses those issues I felt were problems with previous similar proposals. I wonder if it might not be possible to do something like this user-side (via for example a browser extension or similar).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Well, I think that should be easy. If you would have a browser plugin that would allow you to 'replace all' (just like in for instance Microsoft Word) so that you could replace all occurences of for instance '\z' by '\mathbb{z}' that would be just as efficient as the suggestion in the OP.

Comment: These could be useful for that purpose. For Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxreplace/ and for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-and-replace/bldchfkhmnkoimaciljpilanilmbnofo

Comment: @901301 those are pretty useful, thanks

Comment: Another possibility is to edit your OS keyboard shortcuts, for example: `CTRL+z` displays: `\Bbb Z`

Comment: I have asked about solutions which could serve as a workaround if this is not implemented: [Is there some way to include some default text quickly in a post?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31231) And also there is a recent feature request on [meta.se]: [Enable blackboard bold TeX macros \N, \Z, \Q, \R, \C for ℕ, ℤ, ℚ, ℝ, ℂ () in MathJax configuration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343509).

Answer (score 0):

This could be implemented by turning on the [begingroup extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#begingroup) in MathJax.